# What is wrong w/ parse of JSON data using JavaScript from Wordpress & JSON-API

Tags: jquery, json, wordpress, jquery-mobile

I am trying to parse a JSON file that comes from a Wordpress site, using the JSON-API module.   I am using JavaScript, JQuery and JQuery Mobile to display a list of poets from an online poetry magazine that uses Wordpress.  I use a GET request that uses the JSON-API Wordpress plugin to get a list of all the poets/authors.  This GET request returns with a callback function that parses that JSON.  Each poet has a post that serves as their bio page and I attached a photo if one was available.  My callback function tries to populate the JQuery Mobile page with the bio and the photo.  The photo is available in the json data as a thumbnail attribute (not sure if that is the right word).  I get to the thummbnail using dot syntax.  Some of the poets do not have a photo, so I tried to have it then display a default image.  I am getting an errors with regard to entries that do not have a thumbnail value.  It's undefined for some.  I check for that with an if statement, but my app still fails due to where the thumbnail is not defined.

The function is available in this pastebin: http://pastebin.com/L8Mb1dCj
I start with this:

```
$.each(data.posts,function(key,val)
```

then...

```
if (val.thumbnail !== 'undefined')
```

What's wrong with that?  Why doesn't it handle where thumbnail doesn't exist?
Lastly, can this be handled better with a JavaScript template library?  Like Mustache?
The calling script is below.

Thanks,
Bruce

Comment: try `if (typeof val.thumbnail !== 'undefined')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function GetJSONifNeeded(data) {
    if (typeof data == "object")
        return data;
    else
        return JSON.parse(data);
}

function GetJSONstringfyifNeeded(data) {
    if (typeof data == "object")
        return JSON.stringify(data);
    else
        return data;
}
```

TRY THIS